# Parallelizing of a loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

how can I parallelize my loop in python?
this code takes 60-70 seconds and I need to run it for 14400 times. 
Can you please help me to speed up the code.

```
AOD_mask = np.zeros([1200, 1200])
for i in range(0, 1200):
    for j in range(0, 1200):
        if (np.nansum(AOD_MODEL[:, i, j]) == np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(AOD_MODEL[:, i, j])) * 6.):
            AOD_mask[i, j] = 0
        else:
            AOD_mask[i, j] = np.NaN
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't need an if or else since you already have zeros set - so you only looking where to fill in the `np.nan`. As for parallelising the code, not sure you can without having sums already built in the structure `AOD_MODEL`. This could reduce the number of loops you have to make. My final point, I am assuming that the first dimension is rather large to ask for speed up for a 1200, 1200 loop?

Comment: the first dimension is 3

Comment: Then why do you need to parallelise?

Comment: because it takes about 67 seconds and I need to run this 14400 times.

Comment: Add that info to the question.

Comment: I also tried to use multiprocessing: p = Pool(8) 
AOD_mask = p.map(makeAOD_mask, AOD_MODEL.tolist())
but got this error: List indeces must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: The first optimization step in `numpy` is to get rid of the `i,j` loops, writing a test on `AOD_MODEL` that works with the whole thing, rather than a 1d slice.  `For example `nansum(AOD_MODEL, axis=0)` gives a 2d sum.  Same for `count_nonzero`.